# The result is much greater than the error rate

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I have the following script:

```
g4cz = 33.0693964; 
g5idt = 698.131701; 
error = 0.0174533*0.0174533;
sol = FindInstance[{(a*g4cz) - (g5idt*b) <= error, a > 0, b > 0}, {a, b}, Integers, 15];
Sort[sol]
```

And this script is giving me the following result.

```
 {{a -> 13, b -> 561}, {a -> 85, b -> 2108}, {a -> 176, 
  b -> 110}, {a -> 439, b -> 2003}, {a -> 704, b -> 920}, {a -> 940, 
  b -> 2860}, {a -> 1032, b -> 910}, {a -> 1066, 
  b -> 821}, {a -> 1861, b -> 963}, {a -> 2429, 
  b -> 1997}, {a -> 2475, b -> 2654}, {a -> 3319, 
  b -> 1433}, {a -> 3425, b -> 1652}, {a -> 3431, 
  b -> 737}, {a -> 3497, b -> 3329}}
```

However, this is not true, for example, let's take the first answer which is a=13 and b=561
When I put this values in the equation like in the following:

(33.0693964*13) - (698.131701*561) = 391221.982108 which is much bigger than `error`.
I think I am doing something wrong in the syntax. Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot the negative sign. `(33.0693964*13) - (698.131701*561) = -391221.9821` which is less than `error`.

Comment: Oh sorry for it!! Thanks. Then I will add Abs directly: `FindInstance[{Abs[(a*g4cz) - (g5idt*b)] <= error, a > 0, b > 0}, {a, 
  b}, Integers, 15]`

Comment: `FindInstance` can only find one integer solution. `FindInstance[{Abs[(a*g4cz) - (g5idt*b)] <= error, a > 0, b > 0}, {a, 
  b}, Integers]`, `{{a -> 3490658505, b -> 165346982}}`.

Comment: How long did it take for you to have a result? I am running and it is quite long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) all of the constants

```
g4cz = Rationalize[33.0693964, 0];
g5idt = Rationalize[698.131701, 0];
error = Rationalize[0.0174533, 0]*Rationalize[0.0174533, 0];

cond = Abs[(a*g4cz) - (g5idt*b)] <= error && a > 0 && b > 0;

sol =
 Select[
  Table[
    FindInstance[N[cond, wp], {a, b}, Integers][[1]],
    {wp, Range[15, 25]}] // 
  Union,
 cond /. # &]

(* {{a -> 398932254, b -> 18896791}, {a -> 1795195808, 
  b -> 85035591}, {a -> 3490658505, b -> 165346982}} *)
```

**EDIT:** Use [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) to find all answers within a specified range

```
cond = Abs[(a*g4cz) - (g5idt*b)] <= error && 0 < a < 4000 && 
  0 < b < 200;

Solve[cond, {a, b}, Integers]

(* {{a -> 190, b -> 9}, {a -> 380, b -> 18}, {a -> 570, b -> 27}, {a -> 760, 
  b -> 36}, {a -> 950, b -> 45}, {a -> 1140, b -> 54}, {a -> 1330, 
  b -> 63}, {a -> 1520, b -> 72}, {a -> 1710, b -> 81}, {a -> 1900, 
  b -> 90}, {a -> 2090, b -> 99}, {a -> 2280, b -> 108}, {a -> 2470, 
  b -> 117}, {a -> 2660, b -> 126}, {a -> 2850, b -> 135}, {a -> 3040, 
  b -> 144}, {a -> 3230, b -> 153}, {a -> 3420, b -> 162}, {a -> 3610, 
  b -> 171}, {a -> 3800, b -> 180}, {a -> 3990, b -> 189}} *)
```

Comment: what is wp ? And what is range represents here?

Comment: It is the precision specified for `N` to use. The range is 15 to 25 digits of precision in increments of 1.

Comment: and as a final question what is the `Clear["Global`*"]`

Comment: It clears the `Global` context namespace so that any previously assigned definitions do not interfere with the calculations that follow. See the `Generalizations & Extensions` section of the documentation for `Clear`

Answer (score 3):

We can use `((a*g4cz) - (g5idt*b))^2 <= error^2` instead of `Abs`.

```
g4cz = 33.0693964;
g5idt = 698.131701;
error = 0.0174533*0.0174533;
sol = FindInstance[{((a*g4cz) - (g5idt*b))^2 <= error^2, a > 0, 
    b > 0}, {a, b}, Integers, 15];
Sort[sol]
```

[image]